# CSS style shows after refresh and then goes invisible with Knockout

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

So I have a new notification style ring and green circle with unread notifications in it this circle only is visible when you have new notifications.[image: New 1 Notification]

when page is refreshed even if you dont have a notification the circle is visible for a second and then goes invisible

[image]

If there is a new notification still when refreshed circle shows up empty or with zero and then goes invisible and then with correct number

**HTML**:

```
<div class="bell">
    <div class="unseen-notification-show" data-bind="visible: UnSeenMessagesCount() > 0, text: UnSeenMessagesCount()" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.unseen-notification-show {
    content: '';
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -8px;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #8cdb16;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

self.searchModel = new AuthorizedSearchViewModel();
self.Header = ko.observable(new HeaderModel());
self.UnSeenMessagesCount = ko.observable(0);
self.Messages = ko.observableArray();
self.CanShowRemindProfile = ko.observable(false);
self.Remind = ko.observable(new RemindModel());

self.LoadUserInformation = function () {
    $.post('/User/GetUserInfoForDashboardHeader',
        function (response) {
            InitTawkChat(response);
            self.Header(new HeaderModel(response));

            if ($('#accountId').length > 0) {
                $('#accountId').html(response.accountId);
            }

        }, "json").done(function () { console.warn("loaderOff"); });
};

self.GetRemindProfile = function () {
    self.CanShowRemindProfile(false);
    $.post('/User/GetRemindProfile', function (result) {
        if (result) {
            self.CanShowRemindProfile(true);
            self.Remind(new RemindModel(result));
        }
    });
};

self.GetMessages = function () {
    $.post('/Messages/GetAll', {
        page: 1,
        pageSize: 4
    }, function (result) {
        var notifications = [];

        _.map(result.Notifications, function (item) {
            notifications.push(new MessageModel(item));
        });

        self.Messages(notifications);
        self.UnSeenMessagesCount(result.UnseenNotifications);
    });
};
```

Comment: try using position:relative;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `!important` from display property in your css and let knockout inline handle display.

```js
function viewModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.UnSeenMessagesCount = ko.observable();
  
  self.initData = function(){
    //dummy setTimeout for your ajax get.
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      self.UnSeenMessagesCount(4);
   },1000);
  }
  
}

var vm = new viewModel();
vm.initData();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.unseen-notification-show {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
     
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #8cdb16;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="bell">
    <div class="unseen-notification-show" data-bind="visible: UnSeenMessagesCount() > 0, text: UnSeenMessagesCount()" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some loading issues. Try moving your css from being loaded in the top of the HTML, to be loaded in the bottom/footer.

What you want to do, is to hide the circle until the result is loaded (either 0 or 1,2,3,4.. and so on. Depending on the number of notifications).

In your `div` you got this line `style="display:none">` which hides the circle. Thats good!

Now you should make sure that the style for `.unseen-notification-show` which contains `display: block !important;` that shows the circle - Should not be run before the calculation of the number to show is done.

One way could be to place the file that loads your css to the bottom of the HTML (like moving your `<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />`). Or another way is to only use css for the hiding and then use javascript/jQuery for showing the cirle.

If this didn't help - then please provide the code you use to generate the number.

Comment: I tried to make the div first display none and then  to make it visible with data-bind css but the problem is for the circle that works but for then I have the number with data-bind text and number shows 0 shows up like it does with empty circle and without style and disappears and then shows normali. so I think problem is that data binds data binds and style load faster than the code that finds unseen notification numbers

Comment: What happens if you remove the `visible: UnSeenMessagesCount() > 0, ` from the `data-bind` and move your css to the footer?

Comment: if I remove visible it will just stay displayed

Comment: Ok. I don’t have a solution then :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is due to 
self.UnSeenMessagesCount = ko.observable(0);
so when your modal is getting created it is initialized with value 0. So when you refresh the page initially it is 0 but when self.getMessage is called it updates your value.